# Inequality query not working ndb

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

`Session.sessionType` is a `StringProperty(repeated=True)`

When I do this query:

```
sessions_no_type = Session.query(Session.sessionType == request.sessionType)
```

everything seems to be working and I get only those sessions who have `request.sessionType` in them

but when I try:

```
sessions_no_type = Session.query(Session.sessionType != request.sessionType)
```

I get back all sessions (regardless of `request.sessionType`)

What might be the problem for this? Even docs have a similar example but it does not work for me.

The same goes when trying this version:

```
filter = ndb.query.FilterNode("sessionType", "!=", request.sessionType)
```

when tested for equality it returns everything correctly, but inequality case ONLY eliminates Session objects which have ONE sessionType which is equal to the passed(request) `sessionType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [The != and IN Operations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) says:

> The != (not-equal) and IN (membership) operations are implemented by
>   combining other filters using the OR operation. The first of these,
>
> `property != value`
>
> is implemented as
>
> `(property < value) OR (property > value)`

Because you are using a repeated StringProperty, if any of the strings in `sessionType` are not equal to `request.sessionType` then that entity will be returned in the query.

Comment: After reading the documentation I tried that as well, but it did not help. And it also says that `!=` operator is later automatically translated into `> OR <` so it should not make much difference anyways.

Comment: @Kkulikovskis, that's right.  This identifies the cause of your problem.  That was your question, right?

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. I misread the answer a bit. If you could provide a solution, I would be grateful and check your answer.

Comment: Well apparently I have to query for all entities and then filter them through a loop afterwards, because to quote documentation `There is no way to query for entities that do not include a tag equal to 'perl'.`

Comment: Another way would be to put all the `sessionType`s into their own model, maybe with the `Session` key as their parent, so you can do queries on them.